# Date javascript object from IE cannot be automatically bound to Datetime in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a site that uses a jquery calendar to display events.
I have noticed than when using the system from within IE (all versions) ASP.NET MVC will fail to bind the datetime to the action that send back the correct events.

The sequence of events goes as follows.

- Calendar posts to server to get events
- Server ActionMethod accepts start and end date, automatically bound to datetime objects

In every browser other than IE the start and end date come through as:

```
Mon, 10 Jan 2011 00:00:00 GMT
```

When IE posts the date, it comes through as

```
Mon, 10 Jan 2011 00:00:00 UTC
```

ASP.NET MVC 2 will then fail to automatically bind this to the action method parameter.

Is there a reason why this is happening?
The code that posts to the server is as follows:

```
data: function (start, end, callback) {
        $.post('/tracker/GetTrackerEvents', { start: start.toUTCString(), end: end.toUTCString() }, function (result) { callback(result); });
    },
```

Comment: Another great IE feature. Indeed hell confusing. Have a look at this http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5054.aspx

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem and I solved it using JavaScript Date()'s .toISOString() function (rather than doing a string replace).

[See doc here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

`DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` will process this correctly regardless of the broswer sending it (in my limited IE, Firefox, and Chrome testing).

So, I send the date to the controller like so (this is my JS object):

```
var dateObject = new Date();
dateObject.toISOString()
```

And the server can parse the data like so (.NET - in the controller):

```
DateTimeOffset timeInGMT = DateTime.Parse(dateString).ToUniversalTime(); //for the time in GMT
DateTime timeOnClient = DateTime.Parse(dateString); //for time as it was set on the client.
```

Answer (score 3):

try to replace

```
start.toUTCString()
```

with

```
start.toUTCString().replace('UTC','GMT')
```

and see if that doesn't fix the problem for you :)

Answer (score 1):

When I use the function `.toUTCString()` under IE, I had trouble with `UTC` vs `GMT` and also with the leading zeros.

This is what I use to send UTC date to ASP.NET MVC :

```
function getUTCString (date) {

    function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? "0" + n : n }    

    var weekday = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    return weekday[date.getUTCDay()]
        + ", " + pad(date.getUTCDate())
        + " "  + month[date.getUTCMonth()]
        + " "  + date.getUTCFullYear()
        + " "  + pad(date.getUTCHours())
        + ":"  + pad(date.getUTCMinutes())   
        + ":" + pad(date.getUTCSeconds())
        + " GMT"; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this weird situation.
Replacing UTC to GMT in the date string solved my problem but I've wanted to look for another way (replacing strings sometimes cause problems :)).

I've come up with the following solution which worked well in IE, Chrome, and Firefox:

```
var myUTCDateString = (function(d) {
          return d.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (d.getUTCMonth() +1) + "-" +  d.getUTCDate() + " " + d.getUTCHours() + ":" + d.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + d.getUTCSeconds();
     })(new Date());
```

myUTCDateString is something like "2012-1-3 21:47:49".

Answer (score 0):

I've found [here](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html) and modified a helper:

```
// #region Date.prototype.toISONonUtcString
// add Date prototype toISONonUtcString function if it doesn't yet exist
if ($.isFunction(Date.prototype.toISONonUtcString) === false) {
Date.prototype.toISONonUtcString = function () {
    var pad = function (n, places) {
        n = n.toString();
        for (var i = n.length; i < places; i++) {
            n = "0" + n;
        }
        return n;
    };
    var d = this;
    return pad(d.getFullYear(), 4) + '-' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1, 2) + '-' + pad(d.getDate(), 2) + 'T' +
                pad(d.getHours(), 2) + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes(), 2) + ':' + pad(d.getSeconds(), 2) + '.' +
                pad(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);
};
}
// #endregion
```